# Restart countdown timer to every Sunday at 10:30AM

Tags: javascript, jquery, count, countdown, countdowntimer

I'm using the countdown timer from http://git.wimbarelds.nl/TimeCircles/readme.php

```
<div class="example" data-date="2017-09-17 10:30:00"></div>
```

How can I update the value `2017-09-17 10:30:00` with JavaScript so that it changes to `2017-09-24 10:30:00`?

This is the code [on Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lsp4cgts/1/)

Comment: This question is about JavaScript/HTML/CSS, so you should consider using a [snippet](//blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). Snippets are *much* better for Stack Overflow questions than links to JSFiddle, or other off-side code. Stack Overflow requires that everything needed for the question to be complete must be *in the question itself*. While it's OK to have links to off-site resources as supplementary material, if you want it to be part of the question, then the material must be *in the question*.

Comment: what about using php ?

Answer (score 0):

You need a function to find the next Sunday and set time to 10:30am..

```
var getDate = new Date();
var targetDay = 0;

getDate.setDate(getDate.getDate() + (targetDay + (7 - getDate.getDay())) % 7);
getDate.setHours(10, 30, 0, 0);
```

Then you need to set a data node named "data-date" to set the timer.

```
targetNode.dataset.date = strFormat(getDate);
```

To get the date in the right format you need function to do that too.... I have the full solution here [Solution Fiddled](https://jsfiddle.net/rlsmilej/c0uqnbmw/)

Cheers!

Comment: This answer would be significantly improved by putting the code into a [snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). Using a snippet also makes it more likely for it to be up-voted, because people can quickly verify that your code functions correctly. While snippets shouldn't always be used, for JavaScript/HTML/CSS based questions and answers, they can significantly improve communicating both the problem and solution. When possible to use, a snippet is better than runable code examples that are off-site (e.g. JSFiddle).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I appreciate it. But how do I add it so that it updates the data-date? In other words, how may I add the script instead of writing 2017-09-17 10:30:00?

    <div class="example" data-date="2017-09-17 10:30:00"></div>

This is the code [on Fiddle][1]


  [1]: https://jsfiddle.net/Lsp4cgts/1/

Comment: Well the targetNode code finds your div by an ID and sets the data-date attribute. It also sets the the innerHTML that makes the date display on the page. Just remove that part and add an the returnDate ID to your div. I updated your jsfiddle code. https://jsfiddle.net/rlsmilej/Lsp4cgts/5/

Comment: @JohnDoes did you get it going?

Answer (score 0):

I know, your question is about **javascript**, but maybe you can considering to use **PHP**.

```
<div class="example" 
data-date="<?= date('Y-m-d',strtotime('next sunday', strtotime('tomorrow') ));?> 10:30:00">
</div>
```

This one line of code will print always the next sunday

printing:

> 2017-09-24 10:30:00